# Syms Function overwrite Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm working on an script that uses sym functions within a loop, because of the way my functions are defined. Also I need to  use their derivatives. I cannot just write down the explicit matlab function for each, so defining each individual function and derivatives is not an option.

the code is this:

```
[out]=sym_script(n)

syms x;
out=[];

for i=1:n
    Function=sin(x)+i*x;
    out=[out Some_operation(Function,vec)];
end
```

(min example, actual sym function more complicated ) the problem is that matlab seems to be unable to overwrite Function if it is syms.

I have tried the script in Matlab 2015a for pc and mac and get the same error in both.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the trouble was inside other function I called in the loop. It had a variable named "diff" which caused conflict with the matlab's function diff() to calculate derivatives.